# How to mask sensitive information with some dummy value on HTML pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have Medical Record Number on several web pages which I can't show on show because of some conditions. I am using TempData to show Medical Record Number in span.

```
<span id="MRNO"> Name: </span> @TempData["PatientName"].ToString()
```

I need to display XXX on values in overall website, not simply change the values to XXX, like in my attachment screenshot. Please help how can I achieve this thing

[image: Hiding information]

Comment: You can do it easily in `server side`.. what` server side programming` are you using .. and also provide some demo code .. how you designed the `OOP model`..

Comment: I am using C# language, using html razor syntax in this I am showing value from TempData and showing it in span. 
 <span> Medical Record Number: </span> @TempData["MRN"].ToString()
I need to show XXX on this MR Number not the actual number

Comment: Edit your question and provide demo code there man ... it will be much readable ..

Comment: I have made changes to my question, please check.

Comment: Does the X have to be over those values as an overlay or you want to have values displayed as X?

Comment: I want to display X over the number.

Comment: @MahrukhMehmood, If this is sensitive information, then do not send it to the view. Having an overlay is pointless. Anyone can view the page source and see the html including your 'sensitive' information

Answer (score 1):

While you did not provide .. `OOP model` you used .. i made an `demo model` here .. If you structure your model this way .. you can easily .. change the property to use `show data in UI`

```
   public class SomeClass
    {
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public string PatientNameSecret 
        {
            get
            {
                return GetSecretString(PatientName);
            }
        }

        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNoSecret
        {
            get
            {
                return GetSecretString(PhoneNo);
            }
        }

        string GetSecretString(string ValueToReplace)
        {
            if (ValueToReplace==null)
            {
                return ValueToReplace;
            }
            return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("X", ValueToReplace.Length));
        }
    }
```

**Uses**:

```
        SomeClass objSomeClass = new SomeClass();
        objSomeClass.PatientName = "My name is secret";

        //TempData["PatienName"] = objSomeClass.PatientName;
        TempData["PatienName"] = objSomeClass.PatientNameSecret;
        //TempData["PhoneNo"] = objSomeClass.PhoneNo;
        TempData["PhoneNo"] = objSomeClass.PhoneNoSecret;
```

**Note**: `Do not use client side script` to hide or change value in `client side`.. any one `familer with browser` can easily `stole it` from there..

Comment: So you mean I should do this in code, its just for display purpose, but you raised a good point that one should do this from code.

Comment: I prefer to use term `Server-side` rather that `code` .. there are few reasons of that .. anyway if your problem is solved `you can mark it as answer`

Answer (score 0):

use inline scripts or razor to achieve this in your views:

So forexample i use the following script in my create view to toggle field visibility:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ToggleWeight();

        $('#Uom').change(function () {
            ToggleWeight();
        });
    });
    function ToggleWeight() {
        var uomValue = $('#Uom').val();
        if (uomValue == 'some value') {
            $('#sensitive_data').hide();
            $('#label_with_xs').show();

        }
        else {
            $('#sensitive_data').show();
            $('#label_with_xs').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, when a condition is met, replace your field with a label (XXXX) otherwise show sensitive information.

Comment: I need to show the value in background and XXX infront of the value in whole website, can I call a single js function on every page that can do this without writing again and again?

Comment: Sorry just saw but i edited my answer, Dont coppy and paste my code, its just to give you an idea fo how it can be achieved in your view

Comment: What is UoM here ? div id ?

Comment: Let me edit the above i think its not correct in your case

Comment: But this will hide the medical record number which I don't want, I want to show this in background :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104370/discussion-between-cosmos-banda-and-mahrukh-mehmood).

Comment: i created a chat so we can discuss this further